# Starting Visual Studio causes all running apps to hang and stop responding

Tags: visual-studio

After my laptop fell on the floor and its screen was a little damaged, I was able to continue working with it, but failed to build a project of mine. At some point, the system froze, and I was forced to restart the laptop. Ever since, I’m not able to start Visual Studio 2008 or 2010. Moreover, when I do try to start one of the versions, I see no splash screen, and at some point, all running applications stop responding, and I’m forced to restart the laptop.

When I started Visual Studio 2008 with the [/SafeMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278.aspx) flag it started OK and worked perfectly, but when I tried it with Visual Studio 2010, I did see a splash screen and the application main window was opened, but then the system got stuck again and forced me to restart.

I use Windows XP SP3, and the addins I recall I have are [Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/), [IncrediBuild](http://www.xoreax.com/), and [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef) for VS 2010 (how can I check what other addins are installed without having Visual Studio running?)

I tried using the [/Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241272.aspx) flag to find out what’s happening, but there was nothing that seemed related in the generated log.

At the time of the hang, the CPU and memory of the system was low.
The problem happens whether I open Visual Studio with no solution, or with an existing solution.

Do you have any idea why this might happen, or how it can be solved?

**Edit:**
I run **chkdsk /R /V** and it is stuck on "**1 percent
 completed.**" for hours now. Is there anything I can do?
I'll try to re-install Visual Studio 2010 next week, when I'm in the office. I hope that will help.

Thanks a lot,
splintor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your drive is torched. Buy a new drive, and salvage whatever you can from the existing drive, then swap them out. If you're lucky you can salvage enough of the existing drive to not need to do a full OS reinstall, but it's likely you're going to need to do some reinstallation.

Comment: I was going to install Windows 7, so this is not a real problem. However, it seems only part of it was damaged in the fall, and it only affects the starting of Visual Studio. Is this a sign, and the rest of the hard disk is to come, or maybe, if I uninstall and reinstall Visual Studio I can bypass the problem?

Comment: The fact that chkdsk can't fix things doesn't bode well and you're likely to experience problems with other things. You can check this for yourself if you have the patience, by running a 3rd party low level disk check tool on the drive. One possibility would be to download the SystemRescueCD and run TestDisk on the drive.

Comment: My IT staff agreed with you. They ordered a replacement HDD, which was for free, as it was under the warranty. I have now installed Windows 7 on that new HDD, and everything work fine. (The screen still need to be replaced, and that will cost my employer $190, but that's a different story...)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the cause if the fall of your laptop. Though what changes happened is unknown it is more likely to be a hardware issue.

Did you reinstall the softwares and check how they work.

Comment: Reinstalling is my last resort. If I'll get to that, I'll probably install Windows 7 and reinstall the entire machine, but I want to first see if I can handle it without it.

Answer (score 1):

If I was diagnosing this issue, I would start from the ground up.

Start of with a basic CheckDisc - [CheckDisk Instructions for XP](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsupport.microsoft.com%2Fkb%2F315265&ei=g1F_TKb-OJHN4Aajg73TCw&usg=AFQjCNE3xnfT0QKWajC9cWGDWTxn7De5Uw&sig2=3bhke3lNlJDNaDPCtq0r2w)

Progress from that to *try* re-installing over your existing VS install.

I can't see it being a software problem, so I reckon the checkdisk will discover/fix something, or a reinstall should resolve it.

Dave

Comment: Almost every restart (since it is forced restart by long press of the power button) issues a check disk (which makes it even more painful).
That's why I thought it's not a disk problem. I'll try to schedule a full disk check and see if it helps.

Comment: As I said in my edit, running chkdsk /R seems to get stuck. Any idea?

Comment: If chkdsk /r hangs, it sounds as though the drive is damaged. You *may* be lucky and just have data loss (which can't be repaired). At this stage, you really need to get the hard drive checked on the sector level. However, it crashing implies, at least to me, that the drive itself is physically damaged. Having experienced this first hand, I'd advise getting the it replaced as an absolutel priority, it could completely give up at any time depending on how damaged it is... Any attempty to read/write from sectors which are damaged are wasted time/effort and data... Sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

You've probably damaged your hard disk in an area which is touched by VS.  Windows often grinds completely to a halt when it's struggling to read a damaged area of disk.

Check the Windows event log for errors to do with disk drives.

Comment: I don't see anything in the event log that seems related. What should I look for?